# why my postman basic auth not working correctly?

Tags: php, api, authentication, postman, basic-authentication

1. I had added username and password as basic authentication in Postman.

[image: basic auth image]

2. I can see authentication header after sending request too.

[image: authentication header image]

So why I didn't get 401 authentication error if I put some wrong username/password or empty ?

Comment: Does the endpoint your are making your request to actually require HTTP Auth, or are you just sending arbitrary request headers …?

Comment: My https url is like this : https://example.com/controller/function/ . How do I set it through server ? I mean how I get the authentic data from postman api i.e Username and password to the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Authentication need to set your account with basic auth or you can use your environment variable json file to set your details on global for change the header authentication.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Solved]

You need to set body type x-www-form-urlencoded
then put your variables in there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).